# Error in mapping an array in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a problem in mapping an array in React, Here is the problem :
this is my state of the parent element :

```
this.state = {
  grouping: 3,
  bars: [{
    snare: Array(16).fill('0'),
    hihat: Array(16).fill('0'),
    kick: Array(16).fill('0'),
  }]
}
```

i wanna pass the bars to the child element same this :

```
<Bar bar={this.state.bars}>
```

and in 'Bar' class i write this code :

```
class Bar extends Component {
    render(){
        const Bars = this.props.bars.map((bar)=>{
            return('something')
        }
        return({Bars})
    }
}
```

after this codes this error occurs to me :

**Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {Bars}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.**

help me, please

Comment: Why are you returning an object instead of Bars array?

Comment: @devserkan where ?

Comment: `return({Bars})` so, `{}` makes it an object.

Comment: or something like `return (<div>Bars</div>)` instead

Comment: Yes you are skipping JSX in your return as @MichaelSorensen pointed. Though, there should be curly braces this time :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your issue is that a React component should only return a null or JSX.

you should be able to get what you want by doing the following:

```
class Bar extends Component {
    render(){
        return(
            {
                this.props.bars.map((bar)=>{
                    return <div>{bar}<div/>
                })
            }
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks this code worked correctly, but sorry I don't have enough reputation to upvote this answer

Comment: No problem, we are upvoting :)